# Upload image to AWS S3 bucket and serve that image using Amazon CloudFront signed urls

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, cdn

I need to upload an image to AWS S3 bucket and serve that image through Amazon CloudFront. Currently what I am doing is uploading the image to S3 with the specified file name. After uploading using the file name I am generating the CloudFront signed url. I am making two separate calls which I want to avoid. Is there a way where in I can directly upload file to S3 via CDN and get the CloudFront url for that file via java spring boot. Any advice is appreciated.

My current code is as follows. I am uploading multiple files at once. In that case getting CloudFront signed url could be trickier I believe or is there any way to get that in multiple upload as well ?

**upload to s3**

```
public void uploadMultipleFiles(final List<File> files) {

        final TransferManager transferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(amazonS3).build();
        try {
            final MultipleFileUpload xfer = transferManager.uploadFileList(bucketName, null, new File("."), files);
            xfer.waitForCompletion();
        } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
            //do something
        } catch (AmazonServiceException exception) {
            //do something
        }
    }
```

**Get signed url from CDN**

```
public String getCdnUrl(final String s3ObjectKey) {
        final File privateKeyFile = new File(keyPath);
        String cdnUrl = null;
        try {
            cdnUrl = CloudFrontUrlSigner.getSignedURLWithCannedPolicy(Protocol.https, distributionDomain,
                    privateKeyFile, s3ObjectKey, accessKey, DateUtils.parseISO8601Date("2021-06-20T22:20:00.000Z"));

        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException exception) {
    
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
        
        }
        return cdnUrl;
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want to avoid making two separate calls?

Comment: hey @jellycsc I just wanted to know if the functionality can be implemented in a single call or not. Performance wise it would be better so. If it's unavoidable then fine.

Comment: getSignedURL won't make an HTTP request to AWS, so I think your approach is perfectly fine.